# How to include external files when I publish my WPF application?

Tags: wpf, windows, visual-studio-2012, textblock

I'm trying to include .txt files so that I can populate `TextBlock` controls from them. I'd rather not have huge chunks of my Xaml taken up with extra text.

I've found a solution by using C# to find the text files on disk and set the Text property of the `TextBlock`s. But when I go to publish the app, I don't think the text file is included. On the Publish tab of the app properties, the text files don't show up there, so I can't select them to include. Do I have to put those files in a specific place in order to be found?

I've tried to create resources from the text files on the Resources tab of the Properties settings, but can't figure out how to access those resources from within C#.

Is there a best practice solution to this? It seems like it should be easy. I may just have to host the text files online and read them from a consistent location.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to have your txt file deployed with your project, what you can do is to include that txt file into the project, then right mouse click on that file click on Properties and in properties specify in `"Copy to Output Directory"` to `"Copy Always"` or `"Copy if Newer"`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that had no effect. After deploying and reinstalling, the TextBlock is still blank. I can see the new directory in the bin/Debug folder, and I've changed the relative path, but it still comes up blank. I can't even figure out where this application installs to to double check it comes with the deployment.

Comment: Do you see your file in that bin/Debug folder?

Comment: It's there in the directory yes. "bin/Debug/tb/Creating Cultures.txt". I access it with `using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("tb/Creating Cultures.txt"))`

Comment: Try `using (SreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"tb\Creating Cultures.txt"))` instead.

Comment: No luck. Both ways work fine when I test it before it's published. I guess I'll just go with the online reference method.

Comment: @Papa Smurf I think the online method could be problematic if your users do not have internet. Could you explain what you mean by 'publish application'? How exactly are you trying to deploy the app? There are many way to deploy apps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969776.aspx Second, could you please post the full code that you use to populate your textblock? A quick suggestion/thought is to use an absolute path by using GetCurrentDirectory: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @julenka Thank you but I've already removed that code and implemented the online version, which is fine since most of the assets for the program come from an online database. The internet connection is required. But I publish from the Properties->Publish tab to an online server.